# How does the text() function extract the table rows when using lxml xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

The following piece of code outputs exactly what I am looking for, however I'm not sure why. Can someone explain the correlation between `doc.xpath('//tr')` and `row.xpath('.//*/text()')` when traversing rows or a general explanation of `//tr` and `.//*/text()`?

```
import lxml.html                                                                

fi = '/home/jesc/html/oakland-raiders'                                          

doc = lxml.html.parse(fi)                                                       

rows = doc.xpath('//tr')                                                         

data = [row.xpath('.//*/text()') for row in rows]                               

for line in data:
    print(line)
```

This gives the "tr" table rows I am looking to extract:

```
['PASSING']                                                                     
['TEAM', 'ATT', 'COMP', 'PCT', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'YDS/G', 'LONG', 'TD', 'TD%', 'INT', 'INT%', 'SACK', 'YDSL', 'RATE']                                                                       
['Raiders', '596', '379', '63.6', '4051', '6.9', '253.2', '75', '29', '4.9', '7', '1.2', '18.0', '86', '95.3']
['Opponents', '541', '328', '60.6', '4120', '7.9', '257.5', '98', '27', '5.0', '16', '3.0', '25.0', '147', '89.8']
['RUSHING']                                                                     
['TEAM', 'ATT', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'LONG', '20+', 'TD', 'YDS/G', 'FUM', 'FUML', '1DN']
['Raiders', '434', '1922', '4.4', '75', '19', '17', '120.1', '8', '4', '98']    
['Opponents', '421', '1881', '4.5', '64', '10', '18', '117.6', '11', '4', '94'] 
['RECEIVING']                                                                   
['TEAM', 'REC', 'TAR', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'TD', 'LONG', '20+', 'YDS/G', 'FUM', 'FUML', 'YAC', '1DN']
['Raiders', '379', '596', '4137', '10.9', '29', '75', '51', '258.6', '4', '0', '1931', '198']
['Opponents', '328', '541', '4267', '13.0', '27', '98', '61', '266.7', '5', '1', '1858', '188']
['DOWNS']                                                                       
['FIRST DOWNS', 'THIRD DOWNS', 'FOURTH DOWNS', 'PENALTIES']                     
['TEAM', 'TOTAL', 'RUSH', 'PASS', 'PEN', 'MADE', 'ATT', 'PCT', 'MADE', 'ATT', 'PCT', 'TOTAL', 'YDS']
['Raiders', '334', '98', '198', '38', '83', '218', '38.1', '6', '13', '46.2', '147', '1251']
['Opponents', '318', '94', '188', '36', '78', '198', '39.4', '4', '15', '26.7', '115', '1051']
['DEFENSE']                                                                     
['TACKLES', 'SACKS', 'INTERCEPTIONS', 'FUMBLES']                                
['TEAM', 'SOLO', 'AST', 'TOT', 'SACK', 'YDSL', 'TLOSS', 'PD', 'INT', 'YDS', 'LONG', 'TD', 'FF', 'REC', 'TD', 'BK']
['Raiders', '747', '206', '953', '25.0', '147', '40', '70', '16', '147', '40', '1', '21', '14', '0', '2']['Opponents', '813', '207', '1020', '18.0', '86', '45', '60', '7', '84', '45', '0', '10', '7', '0', '1']
['RETURNING']                                                                   
['KICKOFFS', 'PUNTS']                                                           
['TEAM', 'ATT', 'YDS', 'AVG', 'LONG', 'TD', 'RET', 'RETY', 'AVG', 'LONG', 'TD', 'FC']
['Raiders', '26', '534', '20.5', '50', '0', '41', '380', '9.3', '47', '0', '13']
['Opponents', '45', '896', '19.9', '60', '0', '33', '405', '12.3', '78', '1', '15']
['KICKING']                                                                     
['FIELD GOALS', 'EXTRA POINTS']                                                 
['TEAM', 'FGM', 'FGA', 'PCT', 'LONG', '1-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50+', 'XPM', 'XPA', 'PCT']
['Raiders', '29', '35', '82.9', '56', '1-1', '9-9', '6-6', '10-11', '3-8', '37', '39', '94.9']
['Opponents', '22', '26', '84.6', '55', '0-0', '9-9', '5-6', '7-8', '1-3', '35', '39', '89.7']
['PUNTING']                                                                     
['TEAM', 'PUNTS', 'YDS', 'LONG', 'AVG', 'NET', 'BP', 'IN20', 'TB', 'FC', 'RET', 'RETY', 'AVG']
['Raiders', '81', '3937', '72', '48.6', '43.6', '0', '34', '9', '15', '33', '405', '12.3']
['Opponents', '72', '3309', '69', '46.0', '40.7', '0', '20', '5', '13', '41', '380', '9.3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] or a general explanation of //tr and .//*/text()?

In plain English, `//tr` means:

```
select element nodes called `tr` anywhere in the document, regardless of the current
context
```

`.//*/text()` means:

```
.//*      select element nodes with any name, but only if they are a descendant of the
          current context node (".")
/text()   of those elements selected, select all their immediate child text nodes
```

A crucial difference between the two expressions is that the first one does *not* take into account the current context node. The second one does, because it starts with `.`.

It is unclear to me what exactly confuses you about those expressions. I'm glad to expand my answer once you've explained more.

Also, if you would like someone to comment on whether your code makes *sense*, you need to show the input XML document.

**EDIT to reply to comment:**

> The part that confuses/confused me is in the documentation from http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp it states that //= Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are. What is the selection that it is matching?

w3schools is well-known for their inaccurate tutorials, avoid it if you can (btw, it has nothing to do with the W3C). `//` in itself does not select anything; it is not a valid expression on its own.

Probably, what they mean by "selection" is what follows after `//`. The correct name for this "selection" is a **node test**. For instance, the following is a valid expression:

```
//*
  ^ <-- "selection"
```

which will select **element** nodes anywhere in the document, or

```
//@*
  ^^ <-- "selection"
```

which will select **attribute** nodes anywhere in the document.

> Is it what proceeds it (*) or what precedes it (.).

The `//` axis (the so-called `descendant-or-self::` axis) has nothing to with preceding or following, and neither do `*` and `.`. `*` simply selects element nodes, and `.` refers to the current context node.

> So . would be the tr nodes and //* (with asterisk) would be ANY nodes WITHIN the tr nodes?

In this case, yes, exactly. `.` is a `tr` element node, and `//*` will select all element nodes within this `tr` element, not only its immediate children.

Comment: The part that confuses/confused me is in the documentation from `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp` it states that `//`= `Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are`. What is the selection that it is matching? Is it what proceeds it (`*`) or what precedes it (`.`). So `.` would be the `tr` nodes and `//*` (with asterisk) would be ANY nodes WITHIN the `tr` nodes?

Comment: What would be the best method to post the html file that I am working on? This is the link: `http://www.espn.com/nfl/team/stats/_/type/team/name/oak/oakland-raiders` The following syntax extracts the same information that I am looking for `'.//text()'` Is the asterisk redundant for this specific example? Or would it be good practice to explicitly state `*` ?

Comment: @jes516 Stackoverflow requires you to cut down your input file as much as possible and post a minimal version of it in your question (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the full set of rules) - but I don't think it is necessary in your case, because as I understand, your question is answered already. `.//text()` does not mean the same as `.//*/text()`, but if both return the same results in your case, then yes, the `*` step is not necessary.